# Intuition behind the formula: $F = -∇V$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, conservative-field

I have been staring at the following formula for too long and I can't figure out the intuition behind it.

[image: Formula]

I have watched courses about directional and partial derivatives as well as gradients and now I get that $-∇V$ is the vector that goes in the direction that decreases the potential energy the fastest.

But why?
Why does this formula : $F = -∇V$ make any sense?
I do get the proof that's just underneath the formula but I really want to grasp the intuition behind this.

Could this be linked to the principle of least action in Lagrangian mechanics? Because $-∇V$ consists in taking the shortest path along the potential energy curve which means minimizing the potential energy.

**EDIT 1:**
F here is a conservative force.
We're assuming here that V's contribution to the material point's energy is potential energy.

Comment: Don’t understand French but the gradient of the potential is the electric field not force.

Comment: Here we are talking about a conservative force.

Comment: @BobD in many fields, the word *potential* is used as a shortned form of *potential energy*.

Comment: Oh, yes, we're assuming here that V's contribution to the material point's energy is potential energy.

Comment: Might be helpful for intuition: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/732182/

Comment: There is of course a lagrangian link, but the nature of that link is not what you suggest. The most basic example is sufficient to show that. The example: a projectile that is fired straight upward, subject to a uniform gravity. During the first half of the trajectory the projectile is climbing, kinetic energy is being converted *to* potential energy. (During the subsequent descent potential energy is converted back to kinetic energy.) The first half shows: it's not about minimizing potential energy. Instead: the true trajectory has the property: the derivative of Hamilton's action is zero.

Comment: Thanks! I will look that up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it simple and clear: Take a map for hikers. Find the contour lines which indicate the height around mountains. These lines correspond to constant values of $V(x)$. For the hiker which walks along a contour of constant height  -- one could equally say a contour of constant gravitational potential --- the gravitational force $\mathbf{F}$ is perpendicular to the contour line. Imagine the hiker stumbles and thereby falls he will fall perpendicular to the walking direction  (which corresponds to the contour) downwards (we only consider here Newton's approach to gravity).

The mathematical relationship of local value of $V(x)$ and the force $\mathbf{F(x)}$ is the gradient:

$$ \mathbf{F} = - \mathbf{\nabla} V(x)$$

The gradient of a function is perpendicular to the lines of constant value of this function (dimension $> 1$).

As a prerequisite we assume that a scalar potential function can be defined which in other words expressed means that the force is conservative.

**EDIT:**

For completeness it is now demonstrated (rather) mathematically why the gradient is perpendicular to the contour lines.

On the contour lines the value of the potential is constant. In case of a displacement (which is denoted by the vector $d\mathbf{r}$) along a contour line the potential is constant:

$$0= V(\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{dr}) - V(\mathbf{r}) = -\mathbf{\nabla}V(\mathbf{r})d\mathbf{r}   \tag{1}$$

(BTW this is also written in the extract of the textbook copied in the post.)

So the difference of the potential at a certain location $\mathbf{r}$ and a location which is displaced by $d\mathbf{r}$ is zero on the contour line.

On the very right side of (1) the definition of the gradient is used and the result is that

$$\mathbf{\nabla} V(\mathbf{r})\cdot d\mathbf{r} =0$$

It is evident that in this scalar product of 2 vectors,  $\mathbf{\nabla}V(\mathbf{r})$ and $ d\mathbf{r}$ are both vectors that are non-zero. In vector algebra is well known if one has a scalar product being zero that the vectors which are multiplied with each other are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Thanks for this illustration! It makes a lot of sens here because we are talking about the gravitational force F. But how does this idea and illustration apply to other forces, such as the force in elastic spring?

Comment: For a spring it works the same because the force is conservative. $W=\frac{k}{2}\mathbf{r}^2$. Then $\mathbf{F}=-k\mathbf{r}$. If the problem is 1-dim the contour lines degenerate to points (But you can place 2 springs with the same elongation close to each other at the same elongation and draw a line between both elongation points. The force is perpendicular to this line).   The principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine $V$ is given solely by gravitational potential energy, so that $V = mgh$. Lets treat mass and gravity as constants so we just have a function of height $V(h) = mgh$. Intuitively, the potential here is just a measure of how high up you are. We see in this case that $-\frac{dV}{dh} = -mg$, as expected.

Now if we imagine that $h(x,y,z)$ is a function that describes the elevation of some hilly terrain, the $\nabla h$ is just the physical gradient, it points in the direction of highest elevation. Likewise $-\nabla h$ points in the direction of steepest descent. If we write $V(x,y) = mgh(x,y)$ we see that $-\nabla V = -mg \nabla h$, which we see is exactly the manner by which a ball feels force on a sloped terrain.

In general, for most sorts of potentials we can imagine a similar picture - they describe a sort of "abstract elevation" that objects fall down. This is harder to picture when the potential is a 3-dimensional function $V(x,y,z)$ but the intuition is the same.

You're correct in saying that this is related to Lagrangian Mechanics. In the euler-lagrange equations the second law naturally pops out as $m \ddot{\vec x} = -\nabla V$. (As long as the potentials do not depend on velocity)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have accepted the answer below because the example speaks more to me.